# Convert SQL query to Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and tried using many guides and similar Stack Overflow threads but without any luck.

Will anyone help me to rewrite this query to Laravel:

```
SELECT a.id, a.hits, a.url, a.sold, a.total, a.updated_at,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.TransID) as SONumber,
        COUNT(SONumber) AS newHits
FROM    hits AS a
        INNER JOIN transactions AS b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.TransID, a.SONumber) > 0
WHERE   b.TransDate >= '$fromdate' || b.TransDate >= '$todate'
GROUP BY a.id
```

This works perfectly but I don't know how to rewrite it in Laravel.

Tables were not normalized and I had to write such query for it to work properly since I couldn't change given tables.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.hits, a.url, a.sold, a.total, a.updated_at, GROUP_CONCAT(b.TransID) as SONumber, COUNT(SONumber) AS newHits FROM hits AS a INNER JOIN transactions AS b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.TransID, a.SONumber) > 0 WHERE   b.TransDate >= " . $fromdate . " || b.TransDate >= " . "$todate" .  "GROUP BY a.id";
$results = DB::select($query);
```

Not sure if you have a table called `a`and `b` or if those are just placeholders. If not, you'll probably have to interpolate the right table names.

You wouldn't really translate a query 'to Laravel' since Laravel is a MVC framework, not a query language. That said, Laravel does allow you to execute queries with raw SQL when needed.

Comment: I think the OP meant converting it to Eloquent, the Laravel ORM (FWIW I think without any attempt, the question is off-topic though).